# Java Printing API. MS Word files

Tags: java, printing

How to cause printer to print MS Words files, event if printer not natively support   'application/msword' type? I think I need create `SimpleDoc` using 2D Graphics etc...but can't find any example.

P.S. I use `javax.print` (JPS), not `java.awt`...

Answer (score 0):

This links might be useful to [you](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Office/DocumentHandling#DocumentPrinter)

[source](http://www.openoffice.org/api/)